# Can't find Armhf package in apt-get, can find in ubuntu site

Tags: arm

I'm trying to install `owncloud` on CubieTruck, with `armhf` architecture.
When looking in [Ubuntu Package site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/owncloud), it's listed as "all" architecture.
When running `apt-cache show owncloud | grep Architecture` on my x64 PC, I see `Architecture: all` as well.
When trying to find the package in my CubieTruck, I can't find it.

```
root@cubie:~$ apt-get install owncloud 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package owncloud
```

Output of `apt-cache policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security/main Translation-en
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security/restricted armhf Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-security/main armhf Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-security,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates/main Translation-en
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates/restricted armhf Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates/main armhf Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty-updates,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/restricted Translation-en
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/main Translation-en
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/restricted armhf Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/main armhf Packages
     release v=14.04,o=Ubuntu,a=trusty,n=trusty,l=Ubuntu,c=main
     origin ports.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: have you followed this guide: http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:community:testing&package=owncloud-client ?

Comment: @kamil no. I'm mainly interested in finding the missing package in the ubuntu archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the `universe` section of the repos enabled. Note that the `owncloud` package is in the `universe` section.

To do this, you can either run `sudo add-apt-repository universe` or you can edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and manually add in the universe section.